# Raspberry Pi Framebuffer UI in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I seem to have tripped myself up and either don't understand classes or I'm missing a crucial bit of code.

I'm trying to develop a python app for Raspbian that will give me a UI that runs in the framebuffer. It's loosely based on work done for the PiCam that uses a similar UI that I'm having to rebuild because the projects are too dissimilar. I picked snippets that I needed to work and am trying to rewrite the framework to fit my needs. I had everything working until I tried to clean things up by making one of my def entries a class. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here as I just started writing python code about 3 days ago when I started this project.

This code:

```
  ev = pygame.event.get()
  screen.blit(ethdisp,(0,0))
  screen.blit(wldisp, (0,1*font.get_linesize()) )
```

which calls info produced here:

```
class IPdisplay:
    def get_ip_address(ifname):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
            s.fileno(),
            0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
            struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
        )[20:24])
        font            = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        try:
            eth = get_ip_address('eth0')
        except IOError:
            eth = ('0.0.0.0')
        try:
            wl = get_ip_address('wlan0')
        except IOError: 
            wl = ("0.0.0.0")
        if eth == ("0.0.0.0"):
            ethdisp = font.render(ethip, 1, (255,0,0))
        else:
            ethdisp = font.render(ethip, 1, (0, 255, 0))
        screen.blit( ethdisp, (0,0) )
        ethrect = ethdisp.get_rect()
        if wl == ("0.0.0.0"):
            wldisp = font.render(wlip, 1, (255, 0, 0))
        else:
            wldisp = font.render(wlip, 1, (0, 255, 0))
        screen.blit(wldisp, (0,1*font.get_linesize()) )
        wlrect = wldisp.get_rect()
```

gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call Last):                                                 
  File "piface.py", line 188, in <module>                              
    screen.blit(ethdisp,(0,0))    
NameError: name 'ethdisp' is not defined
```

I understand the error, what I don't get is how to fix it. It's calling a variable that is defined in a class that apparently isn't global but I'm missing how to either make it global or call it correctly. I've been searching for hours and I'm not sure why I can't find an answer or if I'm just not sure what to search for. Any help would be appreciated.

If anyone is interested the full code is below and I'm on bitbucket if anyone wants to contribute.

```
import os
import pygame
import time
import random
import socket
import fcntl
import struct
import fnmatch
from pygame.locals import *
os.environ["SDL_FBDEV"] = "/dev/fb1"
if not pygame.font: print 'Warning, fonts disabled'
if not pygame.mixer: print 'Warning, sound disabled'



class Icon:

    def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      try:
        self.bitmap = pygame.image.load(iconPath + '/' + name + '.png')
      except:
        pass

class Button:

    def __init__(self, rect, **kwargs):
        self.rect     = rect # Bounds
        self.color    = None # Background fill color, if any
        self.iconBg   = None # Background Icon (atop color fill)
        self.iconFg   = None # Foreground Icon (atop background)
        self.bg       = None # Background Icon name
        self.fg       = None # Foreground Icon name
        self.callback = None # Callback function
        self.value    = None # Value passed to callback
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            if   key == 'color': self.color    = value
            elif key == 'bg'   : self.bg       = value
            elif key == 'fg'   : self.fg       = value
            elif key == 'cb'   : self.callback = value
            elif key == 'value': self.value    = value

    def selected(self, pos):
        x1 = self.rect[0]
        y1 = self.rect[1]
        x2 = x1 + self.rect[2] - 1
        y2 = y1 + self.rect[3] - 1
        if ((pos[0] >= x1) and (pos[0] <= x2) and
            (pos[1] >= y1) and (pos[1] <= y2)):
            if self.callback:
                if self.value is None: self.callback()
                else:                  self.callback(self.value)
            return True
        return False

    def draw(self, screen):
        if self.color:
            screen.fill(self.color, self.rect)
        if self.iconBg:
            screen.blit(self.iconBg.bitmap,
              (self.rect[0]+(self.rect[2]-self.iconBg.bitmap.get_width())/2,
               self.rect[1]+(self.rect[3]-self.iconBg.bitmap.get_height())/2))
        if self.iconFg:
            screen.blit(self.iconFg.bitmap,
              (self.rect[0]+(self.rect[2]-self.iconFg.bitmap.get_width())/2,
               self.rect[1]+(self.rect[3]-self.iconFg.bitmap.get_height())/2))

    def setBg(self, name):
        if name is None:
            self.iconBg = None
        else:
            for i in icons:
                if name == i.name:
                    self.iconBg = i
                break

# Global stuff -------------------------------------------------------------

screenMode      =  3      # Current screen mode; default = viewfinder
iconPath        = 'icons' # Subdirectory containing UI bitmaps (PNG format)

icons = [] # This list gets populated at startup

buttons = [
    # Screen mode 0 is photo playback
  [Button((  0,188,320, 52), bg='done'),# , cb=doneCallback),
   Button((  0,  0, 80, 52), bg='prev'),# , cb=imageCallback, value=-1),
   Button((240,  0, 80, 52), bg='next'),# , cb=imageCallback, value= 1),
   Button(( 88, 70,157,102)), # 'Working' label (when enabled)
   Button((148,129, 22, 22)), # Spinner (when enabled)
   Button((121,  0, 78, 52), bg='trash',)],# cb=imageCallback, value= 0)],

  # Screen mode 1 is delete confirmation
  [Button((  0,35,320, 33), bg='delete'),
   Button(( 32,86,120,100), bg='yn', fg='yes'),
    #cb=deleteCallback, value=True),
   Button((168,86,120,100), bg='yn', fg='no')],
    #cb=deleteCallback, value=False)],

  # Screen mode 2 is 'No Images'
  [Button((0,  0,320,240)), #cb=doneCallback), # Full screen = button
   Button((0,188,320, 52), bg='done'),       # Fake 'Done' button
   Button((0, 53,320, 80), bg='empty')],     # 'Empty' message
# Screen mode 3 is viewfinder / snapshot
  [Button((  0,188,156, 52), bg='gear',),# cb=viewCallback, value=0),
   Button((164,188,156, 52), bg='play',),# cb=viewCallback, value=1),
   Button((  0,  0,320,240)           ,),# cb=viewCallback, value=2),
   Button(( 88, 51,157,102)),  # 'Working' label (when enabled)
   Button((148, 110,22, 22))], # Spinner (when enabled)
]
ifname=0

class IPdisplay:
    def get_ip_address(ifname):
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        return socket.inet_ntoa(fcntl.ioctl(
            s.fileno(),
            0x8915,  # SIOCGIFADDR
            struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15])
        )[20:24])
        font            = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)
        try:
            eth = get_ip_address('eth0')
        except IOError:
            eth = ('0.0.0.0')
        try:
            wl = get_ip_address('wlan0')
        except IOError: 
            wl = ("0.0.0.0")
        if eth == ("0.0.0.0"):
            ethdisp = font.render(ethip, 1, (255,0,0))
        else:
            ethdisp = font.render(ethip, 1, (0, 255, 0))
        screen.blit( ethdisp, (0,0) )
        ethrect = ethdisp.get_rect()
        if wl == ("0.0.0.0"):
            wldisp = font.render(wlip, 1, (255, 0, 0))
        else:
            wldisp = font.render(wlip, 1, (0, 255, 0))
        screen.blit(wldisp, (0,1*font.get_linesize()) )
        wlrect = wldisp.get_rect()

        #pygame.init()
        #size = (pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h)
        #screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        #pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

        #black = (0, 0, 0)
        #screen.fill(black)
        #screen.blit(ethdisp,(0,0))
        #screen.blit(wldisp, (0,1*font.get_linesize()) )
        #pygame.display.flip()



os.putenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER', 'fbcon')
os.putenv('SDL_FBDEV'      , '/dev/fb1')
os.putenv('SDL_MOUSEDRV'   , 'TSLIB')
os.putenv('SDL_MOUSEDEV'   , '/dev/input/touchscreen')

pygame.init()
#scope = IPdisplay()
#scope.getips()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

# Load all icons at startup.
for file in os.listdir(iconPath):
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.png'):
    icons.append(Icon(file.split('.')[0]))

# Assign Icons to Buttons, now that they're loaded
for s in buttons:        # For each screenful of buttons...
  for b in s:            #  For each button on screen...
    for i in icons:      #   For each icon...
      if b.bg == i.name: #    Compare names; match?
        b.iconBg = i     #     Assign Icon to Button
        b.bg     = None  #     Name no longer used; allow garbage collection
      if b.fg == i.name:
        b.iconFg = i
        b.fg     = None





while (True): # your main loop
  # get all events
  ev = pygame.event.get()
  screen.blit(ethdisp,(0,0))
  screen.blit(wldisp, (0,1*font.get_linesize()) )

  # proceed events
  for event in ev:

    # handle MOUSEBUTTONUP
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        key = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
#        print pos
#        print key
        scope = IPdisplay()
        scope.__init__()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                print "Escape Pressed"
                pygame.quit()
            else:
                print (event.key)
                print "you go nowhere, looping"

    for i,b in enumerate(buttons[screenMode]):
        b.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this part out. I'm not declaring the variable as global. So I need to do something like this:

```
ethdisp = None
```

then in the class whereever I use first I have to use this:

```
global ethdisp
```

then I can use it as normal